# Stripe: Can you add custom bank acocunt numbers to stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to add custom account number/routing numbers to stripe test environment instead of using the default test account numbers?

Comment: Why would you want to? The point of the test account numbers is to ensure that you don't make accidental real transactions.

Answer (score 0):

No, only test account numbers may be used in test mode. Stripe provides multiple test account details per country to allow you to test different outcomes of payouts (eg, for connected accounts): https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#account-numbers

You haven't provided any context on what you're trying to accomplish though, which would help in offering more specific guidance.

Comment: We have to integrate 3 different 3rd party APIs that handle bank accounts, all three are in the same flow but all three have different test account numbers so to test end to end we need the same account numbers in all three apps